# PostGIS Functions in hibernate spatial 6 migration

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate-spatial, hibernate-6.x

**First Issue:**
I have an existing code written for hibernate spatial 5 to find records within given radius, which works fine. I am in the process of migrating the code hibernate-spatial 6.1.7.Final. But getting below error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Passed `invariantType` for function return cannot be null
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.produce.function.StandardFunctionReturnTypeResolvers.invariant(StandardFunctionReturnTypeResolvers.java:45) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.SqmCriteriaNodeBuilder.function(SqmCriteriaNodeBuilder.java:1495) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.SqmCriteriaNodeBuilder.function(SqmCriteriaNodeBuilder.java:153) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at com.adani.amm.specification.AssetLocationSpecification.toPredicate(AssetLocationSpecification.java:35) ~[classes/:na]
```

As per my debugging so far, it seems that POSTGIS **geography** function is not supported in the version.
Below is a snippet of my code.

```
public class AssetLocationSpecification implements Specification<Location> {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final Double radius;
    private final Double latitude;
    private final Double longitude;

    public AssetLocationSpecification(Double radius, Double latitude, Double longitude) {
        super();
        this.radius = radius;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Location> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
        Expression<Geometry> geography = criteriaBuilder.function("geography", Geometry.class, root.get("geometry"));
        Expression<Point> point = criteriaBuilder.function("ST_Point", Point.class, criteriaBuilder.literal(longitude),
                criteriaBuilder.literal(latitude));
        Expression<Point> centerPoint = criteriaBuilder.function("ST_SetSRID", Point.class, point,
                criteriaBuilder.literal(4326));
        Expression<Boolean> expression = criteriaBuilder.function(SpatialFunction.dwithin.toString(), boolean.class,
                geography, centerPoint, criteriaBuilder.literal(radius));
        return criteriaBuilder.equal(expression, true);
    }
}
```

**Second Issue:**
org.hibernate.spatial.SpatialFunction.dwithin is deprecated and replacement enum (org.hibernate.spatial.CommonSpatialFunction) does not contain that function.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error in a project of mine while performing exactly the same migration. I debugged the Hibernate Spatial code which produced the error, and as far as I understand the way the Hibernate types are registered changed in this version of Hibernate Spatial, and the `Geometry` type you use as return type in the first statement can't be found in the list of registered basic types. I can't be more specific because I also did not understand the mechanism completely.

After saying that, this error looked to me too weird and made me considering if the mistake was not on my side. I thought maybe I was using the Spatial APi in an "uncommon" way, and I tried to refactor my code trying to be more generic, without using PostGIS functions directly.

My original code was this:

```
public static Specification<Station> withinBBox(
        final double lon1,final double lat1,
        final double lon2, final double lat2) {
    return new Specification<Station>() {
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Station> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query,
                                     final CriteriaBuilder builder) {
            Expression<Geometry> bBoxExpression = builder.function(
                    "ST_MakeEnvelope",
                    Geometry.class,
                    builder.literal(lon1),
                    builder.literal(lat1),
                    builder.literal(lon2),
                    builder.literal(lat2),
                    builder.literal(4326));
            return builder.isTrue(
                    builder.function(
                            "ST_Within",
                            Boolean.class,
                            root.<Point>get("geoLocation"),
                            bBoxExpression)
            );
        }
    };
}
```

And I refactored to this:

```
public static Specification<Station> withinBBox(
        final double lon1,final double lat1,
        final double lon2, final double lat2) {
    return new Specification<Station>() {
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Station> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query,
                                     final CriteriaBuilder builder) {
            if(builder instanceof SqmCriteriaNodeBuilder) {
                JTSSpatialCriteriaBuilder jtsBuilder = ((SqmCriteriaNodeBuilder) builder).unwrap(JTSSpatialCriteriaBuilder.class);
                Expression<? extends Geometry> bBoxExpression = jtsBuilder.literal(GEOMETRY_FACTORY.createPolygon(new Coordinate[] {
                    new Coordinate(lon1, lat1),
                    new Coordinate(lon1, lat2),
                    new Coordinate(lon2, lat2),
                    new Coordinate(lon2, lat1),
                    new Coordinate(lon1, lat1)
                }));
                Expression<? extends Geometry> stationLocation = root.<Point>get("geoLocation");
                return jtsBuilder.isTrue(jtsBuilder.within(stationLocation, bBoxExpression));
            }
            return builder.isTrue(builder.literal(false));
        }
    };
}
```

You can see I do not use PostGIS anymore to create `Geometry` objects, but a GeometryFactory which I created this way: `new GeometryFactory(new PrecisionModel(), 4326);`

This approach is database agnostic.

Applying the same approach to your case, you could try to write something like this:

```
JTSSpatialCriteriaBuilder jtsBuilder = ((SqmCriteriaNodeBuilder) builder).unwrap(JTSSpatialCriteriaBuilder.class);
GeometryFactory gf = new GeometryFactory(new PrecisionModel(), 4326);
Expression<? extends Geometry> geography = jtsBuilder.literal(root.get("geometry"));
Expression<? extends Geometry> centerPoint = jtsBuilder.literal(gf.createPoint(new Coordinate(longitude, latitude)));
//This is not needed, the geometryfactory already works with SRID 4326
//Expression<Point> centerPoint = criteriaBuilder.function("ST_SetSRID", Point.class, point, criteriaBuilder.literal(4326)); 
Expression<Boolean> isWithin = jtsBuilder.distanceWithin(geography, centerPoint, radius);
```

Comment: Your examples saved me a huge amount of tedious work, thank you